# PostgreSQL: How can I list the tables to which a sequence belongs?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I know I can list all sequences with this:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.sequences;
```

But I need to know by which table this sequence is used.

The reason I want to do this is to find out which sequences of `PRIMARY KEY`s are not in the default format of `table_name_id_seq`

Is this possible?

Note: My PostgreSQL version is 11.5.

Comment: Note that `table_name_id_seq` is the name of a **sequence** (which provides a default value for that colum) - **not** the name of the primary key. The sequence name has nothing to with the primary key - although primary key columns are very often defined with a default value taken from a sequence to make them an "auto-increment" column (e.g. `identity` or `serial` columns).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The information is stored in `pg_depend`:

```
SELECT t.oid::regclass AS table_name,
       a.attname AS column_name,
       s.relname AS sequence_name
FROM pg_class AS t
   JOIN pg_attribute AS a
      ON a.attrelid = t.oid
   JOIN pg_depend AS d
      ON d.refobjid = t.oid
         AND d.refobjsubid = a.attnum
   JOIN pg_class AS s
      ON s.oid = d.objid
WHERE d.classid = 'pg_catalog.pg_class'::regclass
  AND d.refclassid = 'pg_catalog.pg_class'::regclass
  AND d.deptype IN ('i', 'a')
  AND t.relkind IN ('r', 'P')
  AND s.relkind = 'S';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's working perfectly but I also want to know if there is any id column that its sequence is not in the default format (table_name_id_seq) it seems easy but I couldn't succeed to write approriate query. Now output is like this: **table_name column:** schema_name.table_name. I want check if sequence_column is in the format {table_name}_id_seq for all rows. Can you help me?

Comment: Ok. Now finally I wrote the sql I want. So you can ignore the comment above. Thanks again.

Comment: I have postgre 14.4 and I had to swap the third line on the bottom for `AND d.deptype = 'a'`.
Did Postgre change this deptype value?

Comment: @Capaj The correct letter depends on whether you have an identity column or `serial`. I have fixed the query to cover both cases.

Comment: change  AND d.deptype = IN ('i', 'a') to AND d.deptype IN ('i', 'a')

Comment: @des1roer Duh. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_default LIKE 'nextval%';
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain why this would work.

Comment: This was actually a much more straightforward solution, gets you columns with the schema of the table, the table name, and the name of the column that has the auto-increment. Of course there's some potential for it to over-select, like I believe auto-generated UUID columns might get caught by this query, but if all you have is integer/BigInt auto-increment fields, this is actually a great solution, thanks for sharing!